# Confusion regarding STFT phase vocoder-based pitch shifting

Tags: audio, fourier, stft, pitch

I'm currently working on a phase vocoder implementation based on the Short-Time Fourier Transform; it's heavily based on the models described [here](https://serialsjournals.com/abstract/70898_67-nagapuri_srinivas.pdf) and [here](https://music.informatics.indiana.edu/media/students/kyung/kyung_paper.pdf). I have successfully completed the analysis phase, wherein

- $m$ FFT frames of size $N$ are derived from a time-domain signal $x[n]$
- These frames are sampled from equidistant, overlapping locations by a number of samples defined as $hop_a$
- Assuming that $hop_a$ is known and $M$ is the total number of samples being analyzed via the STFT, I believe $m$ can be found via the equation
  $m = \dfrac {M - N} {hop_a} + 1 $

After analysis, the frames are overlap-added back together. When time-stretching/pitch-shifting, the overlap is changed such that the resynthesis hop size is defined as $hop_s = S * hop_a$, where $S$ is the stretching ratio. Theoretically, will result in a buffer of samples that is of length $S * M$, which can then be resampled back into a buffer of size $M$, which will then have a pitch equal to $S$ times its original pitch. For instance, to pitch a 1024-sample block up an octave, it would be put through the STFT, analyzed, and then its frames re-layered into a block of 2048 samples which would finally be resampled back down to 1024 samples, resulting in an octave pitch shift. In the formulas, this is apparently achieved by simply having the synthesis hop size $hop_s$ be equal to $S * hop_a$

**Here is my confusion**: As far as I am able to discern, the math suggests that simply setting $hop_s$ to $S * hop_a$ will not result in an output block of size $S*M$. Taking the above example, assuming $M=1024$ and $N=256$ with $hop_a = 64, S=2.0$,
$$m = \dfrac {1024 - 256} {64} + 1 = 13,$$
$$ m = \dfrac {M_s - N} {hop_s} + 1,$$
$$\therefore M_s = (m - 1)*hop_s + N = (13 - 1) * 128 + 256 = 1792,$$
$$ S * M = 2048 \neq 1792$$
By this logic, using $S=2.0$ would only result in a time-stretch and resulting pitch shift with a ratio of 1.75, or about 9.7 semitones; not the intended 12. I have tried this math out with many input values. I'm fairly certain the issue lies with this pitch-stretching step, as my implementation worked exactly as expected until this point.

What am I missing here? It's been many years since I've been in a math class, so all of this has been self-taught and it wouldn't surprise me if I've missed a very fundamental part of the calculations. As such, my notation might also be confusing; let me know if I can clarify! Thank you!

**EDIT:** I believe my misunderstanding came from trying to think about continuous-time algorithms as if they were to be applied to a finite chunk of samples. For a real-time algorithm, you are simply resampling $hop_s$ samples back into a buffer of size $hop_a$, which will always confer the stretching ratio $S$ you are looking for. Mathematically, this can be thought of as $m$ approaching infinity, thereby negating the issue of $N$ not being divisible by $hop_s$.

Comment: Are you *pitch shifting* or are you *time scaling*?  Is this something you are trying to implement for real-time operation?  Or is it something that you want to apply to sound files?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I'm intending to use this for pitch-shifting, and the end goal is for it to be able to operate in real-time. I'm doing this all with the intention of making a plugin that allows more fine user-level control over the pitch-shifting algorithm for more creative possibilities.

Comment: Well, then there are two approaches, if you're doing the STFT and phase vocoder.  One approach is to do time-scaling first (so that, at first, the pitch is unchanged) that time-stretches or time-compresses the audio, then do resampling (with interpolation) of that stretched or compressed audio back to the original number of samples.  The other approach is to **move** the spectral peaks in the STFT from one location to another in the frequency domain.  But then some kind of interpolation in the frequency domain is needed.  It's tough, choose your poison.

Comment: Now, If you want this to run **real-time**, what do you want the throughput delay to be? Can you handle a throughput delay of 100 or 200 ms? Because that is the ballpark of the minimum delay if you do this in the frequency domain. This is because you will have to input at least 2048 or 4096 samples **before** you can even begin to pass them to the FFT. Even with an infinitely fast computer, you still have to wait until you get enough samples before any decent Fourier Transform. There are time-domain techniques that require a decent pitch detector that are popular for live, real-time operation.

Comment: At current, I'm planning on following the time-stretch and resample method. Though it will be a real-time algorithm, I plan on allowing for a large latency to account for user parameter automation. I've got all that under control though—my question is a specific conceptual one: why does the calculated size of the time-stretched buffer not *exactly* equal the original pitch ratio times the original buffer size?

Comment: looks like you're doing it the right way, then.  If you do not mind having a delay of a large fraction of a second, then do it just as you are.  Do you need some help with that?

Comment: okay, lemme think about your question.  this is going to have something to do with the hop length of the analysis window in your input.  you will end up having a small, one-sample jitter in the placement of that analysis frame.  sometimes your hop length will be $H$, but sometimes it will be $H+1$ in order to have the time-stretch ratio to come out exactly right.

Comment: Thank you for all the assistance! Luckily, I think this was just me realizing an imprecision in the implementation my algorithm is based off of, i.e. that for finite-time sequences, the STFT output won't *exactly* be the input size * pitch ratio. For a real-time algorithm, this isn't an issue. Thanks for the tip on the hop-size though, I was definitely also having some trouble getting my resampling right!